# C - Signal handlers and Kill() not working to communicate through 2 processes

Tags: c, unix, process, signals

As an assignment I got at my university to send arguments to Server, then server needs to calculate and send the result back to the Client.
I need to make 2 .c files(client and server).
Then, compile them using gcc command(gcc client.c -o client.out) and run the server first, let it run in the background(CTRL+Z), get it's PID('ps' command) and then run the client with those arguments:

[image]

The code is written in C, and my workspace is Linux terminal using Putty.
The problem is that when I use the "kill" command in my client file(I called it "c.c") in order to send a signal to a specific process that I have it's PID(which is the server) , The handler of the server doesn't wake up and start working and of course because of that, it won't send a "kill" command back to the client with result.
Jokes aside, I literally sat 24 hours(I'm mean.. for real lol), and since it's 5am I really need to get some rest I'm starting to get delusional and I have less then 24 hours to submit the assignment :( .
Below I shared my code, I hope it's understandable, I tried to do my best guys.

Client.c:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#define GODEL 100

char* reqArgs[5];

void sigterm_handler(int dummy)
{
    char msg[150];
    int clientPID, toClientFD, res, signalCharsR;
    pid_t pid;
    clientPID = getpid();

    char* toClientFileName = (char*)malloc(strlen("to_client_") + strlen(reqArgs[4]) + strlen(".txt") + 1);
    strcat(toClientFileName, "to_client_");
    strcat(toClientFileName, reqArgs[4]);
    strcat(toClientFileName, ".txt");

    // Open the result file(to_client_XXXXX) from Server
    toClientFD = open(toClientFileName, O_RDONLY, 0777);
    if(toClientFD == -1)
    {
        sprintf(msg, "Could not Open file: to_client_%d.txt\n", clientPID);
        write(2, msg, strlen(msg));
        exit(-1);
    }

    // Read the result from the results file(to_client_XXXXX)
    signalCharsR = read(toClientFD, msg, strlen(toClientFileName));
    if(signalCharsR == -1)
    {
        sprintf(msg, "Could not Read result from file: to_client_%d.txt\n", clientPID);
        write(2, msg, strlen(msg));
        exit(-1);
    }

    write(1, msg, sizeof(msg));

    signal(SIGTERM, sigterm_handler);
    
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char msg[150];
    int logFD, reqFD, charsR = 0;
    pid_t pid;
    
    if(argc != 5)
    {
        strcpy(msg, "Wrong number of arguments\n");
        write(2, msg, strlen(msg));
        exit(-1);
    }

    signal(SIGTERM, sigterm_handler);

    for(int i = 0; i<argc; i++)
        reqArgs[i] = argv[i];

    // Open request.txt, Creates it if doesn't exist
    reqFD = open("request.txt", O_CREAT | O_RDONLY | O_WRONLY | O_APPEND, 0777);
    if(reqFD == -1)
    {
        strcpy(msg, "Could not Create and Open file: request.txt\n");
        write(2, msg, strlen(msg));
        exit(-1);
    }

    // Open cLog.txt file
    logFD = open("cLog.txt", O_CREAT | O_RDONLY | O_WRONLY | O_APPEND, 0777);
    if(logFD == -1)
    {
        strcpy(msg, "Could not Create and Open file: request.txt\n");
        write(2, msg, strlen(msg));
        exit(-1);
    }
    close(1);
    dup(logFD);
    close(logFD);
    
    // Writing into request.txt
    for(int i = 2; i<argc; i++)
    {
        charsR = write(reqFD, argv[i], strlen(argv[i]));
        if(charsR == -1)
        {
            strcpy(msg, "Could not write to file: request.txt\n");
            write(2, msg, strlen(msg));
            exit(-1);
        }
        write(reqFD, "\n", 1);
    }
    char mypid[5];
    sprintf(mypid, "%d", pid);
    write(reqFD, mypid, sizeof(mypid));
    close(reqFD);
    
    signal(SIGTERM, sigterm_handler);

    // Sending KILL to the Server
    if(kill(atoi(argv[1]), SIGTERM) == -1){
        write(2, "Could not send signal\n", strlen("Could not send 
        signal\n"));
    }
    
    // Sleeping until Server sends back a result
    while(1){
        sleep(1);
    }

    exit(1);
}
```

Server:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>

int calculator(int x, int y, int op)
{
    switch(op)
    {
        case 1:
            return x+y;
            break;
        case 2:
            return x-y;
            break;
        case 3:
            return x*y;
            break;
        case 4:
            if(y == 0)
                return -1;
            return x/y;
            break;
        default:
            return -1;
    }
    return -1;
}

void sigterm_handler(int dummy)
{
    char msg[150];
    pid_t pid;

    // Forking
    pid = fork();
    if(pid < 0)
    {
        //printf("EX2_FROM_ERROR\n");
        strcpy(msg, "Could not Fork\n");
        write(2, msg, strlen(msg));
        printf("Could not Fork\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else
    {
        // Son
        if(pid == 0)
        {
            int logFD, fd, bytesRead, x, y, op, res;
            char ch;
            char* reqArgs[4];

             // Open request.txt file
            fd = open("request.txt", O_RDONLY, 0777);
            if(fd == -1)
            {
                strcpy(msg, "Could not open file: request.txt\n");
                write(2, msg, strlen(msg));
                exit(-1);
            }

            //  Reading lines from request.txt file;
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                int j = 0;
                bytesRead = read(fd, &ch, 1);

                    while(ch != '\n' && bytesRead != 0) {
                    reqArgs[i][j] = ch;
                    bytesRead = read(fd, &ch, 1);
                    j++;
                }
                reqArgs[i][j] = '\0'; // put null at the end
            }
            close(fd);  // Close request.txt File


            // Initialize the data into variables
            x = atoi(reqArgs[0]);
            op = atoi(reqArgs[1]);
            y = atoi(reqArgs[2]);
            printf("%d+%d+%d=", x, op, y);


            // Creating result file to send to the client
            char* toClientFileName = (char*)malloc(strlen("to_client_") + strlen(reqArgs[3]) + strlen(".txt") + 1);
            strcat(toClientFileName, "to_client_");
            strcat(toClientFileName, reqArgs[3]);
            strcat(toClientFileName, ".txt");

            fd = open(toClientFileName, O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_APPEND, 0777);
            if(fd == -1)
            {
                sprintf(msg, "Could not Create and Open file: %s\n", toClientFileName);
                write(2, msg, strlen(msg));
                //printf("Could not Create and Open file: %s\n", toClientFileName);
                exit(-1);
            }


            // Calling the calc() function
            res = calculator(x, y, op);
            if(res =! -1)
                write(fd, &res, sizeof(res));
            else
                write(fd, "Calculate went wrong\n", strlen("Calculate went wrong")+1);

            close(fd);
            signal(SIGTERM, sigterm_handler);

            char test[5];
            sprintf(test, "%d", atoi(reqArgs[3]));
            // Sending KILL back to the Client
            if(kill(atoi(test), SIGTERM) == -1){
                 write(2, "Could not send signal\n", strlen("Could not send 
                 signal\n"));
            }
        }
        // Father
        else
        {
            
        }
    }
    signal(SIGTERM, sigterm_handler);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    signal(SIGTERM, sigterm_handler);

    while(1){
        sleep(10);
    }

    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Suggest you to debug. Add print statements in your server's child process code and see what happens.

Comment: BTW instead of stopping the server, you can run the server process in the background like `./s.out &`

Comment: @kiner_shah Already done a debug, and as I mentioned it seems to me that the signals are not sending to the Server and back to the Client. I put "printf" in almost every line both in Client and Server and the output command inside the handlers won't show up so it seems like it won't get inside the handlers at all.

Comment: @kiner_shah eventually I removed the printf and replaced ALL the printf inside the handlers to write() command since I read that printf is not good to be inside handlers.

Comment: Did you check if it actually the signal handler is called when the server receives SIGTERM? Try placing a printf immediately at the start of the handler.

Comment: @kiner_shah Yeah I checked that, I put "kill(atoi(argv[1]), SIGTERM);" inside IF statement in order to check if it return -1 but it seems it didn't.  Also, I tried what you suggested me to put printf() right under the handler function but still I don't get the message on screen.

Comment: Trying running server in background like `./s.out > server_log.txt&` and then run client code. Maybe the print statement is not shown because you had stopped your server (using Ctrl + Z?).

Answer (score 1):

`ctrl-z` merely **stops** the forground process. It does not send it to the background. You need to resume the process as *background process* using `bg $n` where `n` is the job number shown in brackets after you stopped the server, `[1]` as seen in your terminal screenshot:

```
bg $1
```